# Triple Table Join with Subtraction

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables (production, sales, wastage)
All 3 tables have the columns: Product and Quantity
I need a query statement that will join all 3 tables in the following manner:
production - sales - wastage
 Grouped by Product

Thanks in advance for the tips and tricks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  In general, questioners are expected to provide the code they have tried and the specific point at which they are stuck, rather than a general problem statement, which is why your question is being downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine tables using left join, group by product and get total quantity by substracting values assuming that there can be no record for a given product within sales or wastage tables and then count them as 0.

```
select p.product, sum(p.quantity - coalesce(s.quantity,0) - coalesce(w.quantity,0)) as qty
from production p
left join sales s on p.product = s.product
left join wastage w on p.product = w.product
group by p.product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group each table individually and then [left] join them:

```
SELECT p.product, p_quantity - COALESCE(s_quantity, 0) - COALESCE(w_quantity, 0)
FROM      (SELECT   product, SUM(quantity) AS p_quantity
           FROM     production
           GROUP BY product) p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   product, SUM(quantity) AS s_quantity
           FROM     sales
           GROUP BY product) s ON p.product = s.product 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   product, SUM(quantity) AS w_quantity
           FROM     wastage
           GROUP BY product) w ON p.product = w.product
```